# What type of list does list() return?

Tags: java, hibernate

The following query gets the username from the User entity.

```
String hql = "SELECT userName FROM User WHERE email= :user_email";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("user_email", userSearched );
```

What type does 'query.list()' return ?

Will it return List?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Well why don't you try it and let us know as there appears to be conflicting opinion. In line with the answers by dsvander or Sumit Singh I would guess you will not get a List<User> but would guess at a List<String>.

Comment: Beware of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Your `createQuery(hql).list()` will return `List` and its not typed. From [Java Doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29)

> Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

Answer (score 2):

Actually it will depends upon what type of query that you have used

As i know it will return **Two types of List**

1. `List<bean>`

   - Contains the whole data records of a table, when you use like `createQuery('from table').list()` returns this list, because you retrieve all column records from table.
2. `Object[]`

   - When you specify a particluar column name or names like `createQuery('select column1,column2 from table').list()` , it will return `object[]`, here every column  will be retrieved as `object[0],object[1],...`

Answer (score 1):

You specifiy fields in your query.
The query will result a list of Object[].

You can use a Mapper to map these to an object or reference them by index.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will return `List<Object>`

From docs [Query#list](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29)

```
public List list()
      throws HibernateException
```

Return the query results as a List. If the query contains multiple results pre row, the results are returned in an instance of Object[].

So, below code will return Object list.

```
String hql = "SELECT userName FROM User WHERE email='" + userSearched + "'";
List<Object> usersList = sess.createQuery(hql).list();
```

You can type cast to create [`ArrayList<User>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

```
String hql = "FROM User WHERE email='" + userSearched + "'"; //changed the query
ArrayList<User> usersList = (ArrayList<User>) sess.createQuery(hql).list();
```

---

**Not related**

I would recommend use [Query#setParameter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to set the parameter.

```
String hql = "FROM User WHERE email = :userSearched";
ArrayList<User> usersList = (ArrayList<User>) sess.createQuery(hql).setParameter("userSearched",userSearched).list();
```

Comment: Are you sure? User is selecting fields. I would not expect a List<User> from this but more likely a List<String>: "SELECT userName FROM User"

Comment: The Objects in the List will be Strings! http://www.javajee.com/introduction-to-hibernate-query-language-hql

Comment: @AlanHay : You need to type cast to (List<String>). see in your document `Selecting fields in HQL`

Answer (score 0):

createQuery will return object of type List interface i.e. only List. In your case since you know that it will be list of User object to can explicitly cast to List